# xymatrix syntax problem

Tags: errors, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

```
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{
C_1 \ar[d]^b \ar[l]^{1-t} &C_1 \ar[d]^{-b'} \ar[l]^N &C_1 \ar[d]^{b} \\
C_0          \ar[l]^{1-t} &C_0 \ar[l]^{N}           &C_0}
\end{displaymath}
```

outputs

[image]

while

```
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{
C_1 \ar[d]^b \ar[r]^{1-t} &C_1 \ar[d]^{-b'} \ar[r]^N &C_1 \ar[d]^{b} \\
C_0          \ar[r]^{1-t} &C_0 \ar[r]^{N}           &C_0}
\end{displaymath}
```

gives [image]

But I really need horizontal lines to go from right to the left as in first code. I am not really familiar with `xypic` package, I tried to read some document, but still can't figure out what did go wrong in the first code. 
Any insight or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the arrows in the proper cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{
  C_1 \ar[d]^b & C_1 \ar[l]_{1-t} \ar[d]^{-b'} & C_1 \ar[l]_{N} \ar[d]^{b} \\
  C_0          & C_0 \ar[l]_{1-t}              & C_0 \ar[l]_{N}
}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, reverse the arrows (but point them right nonetheless):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{
  C_1 \ar[d]^b \ar@{<-}[r]^{1-t} & C_1 \ar[d]^{-b'} \ar@{<-}[r]^N & C_1 \ar[d]^{b} \\
  C_0          \ar@{<-}[r]^{1-t} & C_0 \ar@{<-}[r]^{N}            & C_0
}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{tikzcd}
  C_1 \arrow[d,"b"]   \arrow[r,leftarrow,"1-t"] &
  C_1 \arrow[d,"-b'"] \arrow[r,leftarrow,"N"] &
  C_1 \arrow[d,"b"] \\
  C_0 \arrow[r,leftarrow,"1-t"] &
  C_0 \arrow[r,leftarrow,"N"] &
  C_0
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]